# What is good for creating a database with atleast 1000 items per table?

Tags: mysql, vb.net

I want to ask some tips to all experts out there. I want to create a construction supply inventory and management system. We know that it has different product category(E.g. Aggregates, Paints And Chemicals, Plumbing etc.) In every Product category it is possible to have atleast 1000 product items. So is it good to create a table in every category or create only one table and put all product there?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: One table, with a column denoting what category an item is part of. MySQL can handle millions of rows - 1,000 is trivial.

Comment: Thanks. It help me a lot. I know its simple but i cant find a good answer in internet.

Comment: Because I think, it is faster to search a data in a table with a lesser row. And i came to conclusion to create a table in every category so that if i want to search a specific item. It will not take much time.

Comment: The difference will be effectively zero in a 1,000 row table, especially if you put an index on the category column. Splitting it up also adds a lot of complexity if you ever need to change the table structure, make it very difficult to run queries across more than one category, etc. **Do not split them up, it is a horrible idea.**

Answer (score 1):

There isn't really any good reason to use multiple tables with the same layout instead of a single table (at least not in your case), but there are several reasons to use a single table:

- Databases are built to handle a lot of records in a table, but not so much to handle a lot of tables.
- Execution plans can be reused for queries to the same table, but an execution plan for one table can not be resused for a different table. Each query for a new category needs a new execution plan. Caching execution plans for all tables uses memory that could be used to cache data.
- If you need to do any change to the table, like adding a field or adding an index, it's a lot easier to do that to a single table than to do it to multiple tables.
- To access different tables depending on a value you need to create queries dynamically. To concatenate values into queries brings security issues like SQL injection.
- By using data as table names you lose the separation between the data and the database layout. When data changes it should not require the database design to change.
- If you ever need to get products from more than one category at once, that gets much more complicated with categories in separate tables.